# List Index Out Of Bounds when deleting elements from TObjectList

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tobjectlist

I got a small but annoying problem with my Delphi School Project. At school we have to use Delphi 5 (I know, very modern) and to be able to work on it on my own without running into major annoyances, I use Delphi 7 here instead of Lazarus.

I am trying to code a small Space Invaders project with the limited OpenGL knowledge we got taught in our lessons and I am running into the problem when checking the collisions between the bullets the player shoots and the enemies. 
The Collision Detection Code actually works and counts hits accordingly but when it has to delete the enemy & the bullet from a List (so that they won't be rendered anymore), the List Index Out Of Bounds Error occurs.

```
procedure TForm1.CheckCollision(enemies, bullets: TObjectList);
var ll, kk: integer;
begin
  for ll := Form1.bullets.Count-1 downto 0 do
  begin
      for kk := Form1.enemies.Count-1 downto 0 do
      begin
        if TBullet(Form1.bullets[ll]).tby1 >= TEnemy(Form1.enemies[kk]).tey1 then
        begin
          if TBullet(Form1.bullets[ll]).tbx2 > TEnemy(Form1.enemies[kk]).tex1 then
          begin
            if TBullet(Form1.bullets[ll]).tbx1 < TEnemy(Form1.enemies[kk]).tex1 + 0.05 then
              begin
                if TBullet(Form1.bullets[ll]).tby1 <= TEnemy(Form1.enemies[kk]).tey2 then
                begin
                  Form1.enemies.Delete(kk); //error happens here and line below
                  Form1.bullets.Delete(ll);
                  inc(score);
                end;
              end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

This is the code where this error occurs. I do kinda know what this error means but I don't know how to fix it in this instance. The funny thing is, that while in the .exe of this project this error still happens, both the bullet and enemy get deleted and your score gets increased, you just have to quickly press OK after the error message appears and you can continue playing. In Delphi, the program stops after the error obviously.

Hope you guys might be able to help me out here.

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code to see what your variables are doing. The error means that `kk` is not within the low or high bounds of the ObjectList, but we don't have the other data that would allow us to debug it to find out why.

Comment: What @KenWhite says.  1)  This is probably not the cause of your problem, but you should remove all the `Form1` references from your code:  `Form1` refers to a specific instance of the TForm1 class, which is not necessarily the one in use when your code executes.   2)  Use `Assert` in your code and/or turn RangeChecking on to check that `kk` and `ll` refer to valid array elements.  3)  Learn to use the debugger.

Comment: Ok, so I used `Assert` and found out that the error seems to occur when the bullet, which hit the enemy, gets deleted (so the `ll` part). `Assert(bullets.Count-1 >= 0);` right after the Delete throws an AssertionFailure, though that only happens if I shoot once. If I shoot twice, one bullet missing an enemy (on purpose), the second hitting it, the Assertion does not fail and I get an `List Index Out of Bounds(1)` error this time around

Comment: @MartynA I did also remove all the `Form1` references now, didn't change much. These were just a leftover of a battle with an older error/bug

Comment: Might not have changed anything for now, but eventually references like Form1 in your code will come back to bite you, and they are completely avoidable.  Btw, you should really include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a q like this.  Anyway, is the `OwnsObjects` property of your ObjectLists set to `True` and, if it is, does the problem appear to go away if it is set to False instead?

Comment: Alright, I'll keep that mind for future use. Yeah I see how an MCVE might be useful here, didn't think of that sorry. I'll test that first thing in the morning, though even with my rather limited knowledge about the `OwnsObjects` property I doubt it's gonna change much.

Comment: FWIW, I hope you realize you probably could turn this into a single *if*, more or less like `if (....tby1 < ....tey1) and (...) and (...) and (...) then` etc.

Comment: I know that, yes. I am not new to programming, but putting all that in one line would've looked really weird (in the Delphi 7 Editor) and I don't know how Delphi (or Pascal I guess) handles line breaks in if statements.

Comment: May I suggest creating 2 local variables lEnemy and lBullet, and assignign them right after each corresponding for..begin. if you than apply that in the collision check code it is a LOT more readable. And more optimized due to faar less list access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bullet[ll] is deleted in the first kk loop. Hence, in subsequent kk loops, bullet[ll] no longer exists (i.e ll - 1 is "highest" existing index)...

Comment: That's not correct. First, the loop is iterating downward, not upward. Second, the exception is occurring on `kk`, not `ll`.

Comment: Sorry, missed it failed on kk. The downward loop for ll is exactly why it fails (following kk still refs the same ll). On ll that is (comment "...and line below")

Comment: Sorry for the misleading comment, I have now concluded that it must have something to do with the `ll` thing not the enemy list.

Comment: You are right, Mark. OP needs to break out of the inner loop (`for kk`), when a hit is found. E.g. adding `break;` after `inc(score);`

Comment: @TomBrunberg this fixed it, thank you! Kind of obvious in hindsight but I guess I am just used to more lenient code (especially when it comes to loops)